# Get href links & Text in python loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape informations from the apple store, I have a hashmap `hashmap_genre_link` with genre and a URL ( {'Games': 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games/id6014?mt=8' ; ...} ), I want to create for each key an other hashmap with iOS apps (text) and app url as a value : games_apps:{'Pokemon Go','[https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pokémon-go/id1094591345?mt=8](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pok%C3%A9mon-go/id1094591345?mt=8)' : ...}.

Here is my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from requests import get

links = []
ios_categories_links=[]
hashmap_genre_link ={}
url = "https://itunes.apple.com/US/genre/ios/id36"
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
categories_class = html_soup.find_all('div',class_="grid3-column")
# cat = categories_class.text
href = html_soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for j in href:
    # print(j['href'])
    links.append(j['href'])

#
# Hasmap initialisation : hashmap_genre_link = {"games" : "https://link_for_games_page"; etc...}
for i in links:
    if "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios" in i:
        genre = i.split("/")[5][4:] #We get the genre, without 'ios-'
        hashmap_genre_link[genre] = i
        ios_categories_links.append(i)

#print(hashmap_genre_link)


for the_key, the_value in hashmap_genre_link.items():
    #print(the_key, 'corresponds to', the_value)
    print("=======================")
    print(the_key)
    response_genre_link = get(the_value)
    html_soup_genre_link = BeautifulSoup(response_genre_link.text,"html.parser")
    genre_popular_apps_class = html_soup_genre_link.find_all('div',class_="grid3-column")
    for x in genre_popular_apps_class:
        print(x['href'])
```

Here is a part of the output:

```
=======================
games-family
<div class="grid3-column" id="selectedcontent">
<div class="column first">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trivia-crack/id651510680?mt=8">Trivia Crack</a> </li>
<li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/minion-rush/id596402997?mt=8">Minion Rush</a> </li>
<li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/draw-something-classic/id488628250?mt=8">Draw Something Classic</a> </li>
```

How can I get the href tag in a value. (For the text I know I can use .text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea with `['href']` to get those attribute values. however, you need to isolate those. Your `x` elements contain all those hrefs with the `<a>` tags. So you'll need to do an additional `x.find_all('a')`, then iterate through those and print off each `href` attribute for each of those `<a>` tags.

So what I added:

```
for x in genre_popular_apps_class:
        alpha = x.find_all('a')   
        for beta in alpha:
            print (beta['href'])
```

**Full Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from requests import get

links = []
ios_categories_links=[]
hashmap_genre_link ={}
url = "https://itunes.apple.com/US/genre/ios/id36"
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
categories_class = html_soup.find_all('div',class_="grid3-column")
# cat = categories_class.text
href = html_soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for j in href:
    # print(j['href'])
    links.append(j['href'])

#
# Hasmap initialisation : hashmap_genre_link = {"games" : "https://link_for_games_page"; etc...}
for i in links:
    if "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios" in i:
        genre = i.split("/")[5][4:] #We get the genre, without 'ios-'
        hashmap_genre_link[genre] = i
        ios_categories_links.append(i)

#print(hashmap_genre_link)

results_dict = {}
for the_key, the_value in hashmap_genre_link.items():
    #print(the_key, 'corresponds to', the_value)
    print("=======================")
    print(the_key)
    response_genre_link = get(the_value)
    html_soup_genre_link = BeautifulSoup(response_genre_link.text,"html.parser")
    genre_popular_apps_class = html_soup_genre_link.find_all('div',class_="grid3-column")
    for x in genre_popular_apps_class:
        alpha = x.find_all('a')
        links = [ beta['href'] for beta in alpha ]

    results_dict[the_key] = links
```

**Output:**

```
....
=======================
games-racing
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bike-race-free-style-games/id510461758?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hill-climb-racing/id564540143?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/csr-racing/id469369175?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/real-racing-3/id556164008?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/asphalt-8-airborne/id610391947?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/csr-racing-2/id887947640?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smashy-road-wanted/id1020119327?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/happy-wheels/id648668184?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds-go/id642821482?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/need-for-speed-no-limits/id883393043?mt=8
...
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you ! Do you know how I can iterate to create dictionaries for each genre : popular_apps_games-racing, etc ...

Comment: Ya. You’ll initialize an empty dict, then as you iterate, creat that key and value within. When I get a chance I’ll add that to the code. So you want something like the genre as the key, then the list of links as the value?

Comment: Yes exactly what I need

Comment: @userHG just updated it. I removed the print line, but you can always add that back in if you want it